# This saved data doesn't appear to be accessible until relaunch iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `NSCoding` class which stores and retrieves itself when necessary. However, it doesn't feed data to my table view until giving one entry to the array of custom `Person` objects inside it and restarting the app, then giving another. The first one disappears, however.

After that, it appears to load okay.

Here is the implementation of the class

```
#import "DataStorage.h"

@implementation DataStorage


@synthesize arrayOfPeople = _arrayOfPeople;

+ (DataStorage *)sharedInstance
{
    static DataStorage *state = nil;
    if ( !state )
    {
        NSData *data =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DataStorageBank"];

        if (data)
        {
            state = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        }
        else
        {
            state = [[DataStorage alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return state;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {


        if ([decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"]) {
            _arrayOfPeople = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"] mutableCopy];
        } else {
            _arrayOfPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:_arrayOfPeople forKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"];
}

- (void)save
{
    NSData *appStateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appStateData forKey:@"DataStorageBank"];
}


@end
```

I add objects to the `_arrayOfPeople` like so:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName personSurname:surname personCompay:company personPosition:position personEmail:email personMobile:mobile personProduct:product];

        [[DataStorage sharedInstance].arrayOfPeople addObject:person];
        [[DataStorage sharedInstance] save];
```

And load them into the table view by this:

```
Person *personAtIndex = [[DataStorage sharedInstance].arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_arrayOfPeople addObject:personAtIndex];
    cell.textLabel.text = personAtIndex.firstName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = personAtIndex.surname;
```

Loading them  in to the table view is in the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only initialize `_arrayOfPeople` in `initWithCoder:`.  However, if your data does not exist in user defaults already, you use `state = [[DataStorage alloc] init]` to initialize your shared instance.  This does not call `initWithCoder:` so `_arrayOfPeople` is `nil` until after you save and load again, when it is finally initialized as `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.  To fix this, move `_arrayOfPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` out of `initWithCoder:` and into `init`.  (You could alternatively move it into `sharedInstance`, but it makes more sense in `init` since it is not specific to configuring the shared instance.)

Unrelated, but also make sure you synchronize.

```
- (void)save
{
    NSData *appStateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appStateData forKey:@"DataStorageBank"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: i remember... nsuserdefaults should be synchronized, thanks. but still not working!

Comment: I looked over your code again and edited my answer.  This should solve it now.